# Symfony - Twig - dateTime HH:MM:SS.MMM in SS.MMM?

Tags: symfony, twig

How to convert a datetime `HH:MM:SS:mmm` in `SS.mmm` with a filter in Twig please ( `` )?

exemple :
00:01:30.600 => 90.600

I tried that `{{ Object.time | date("s") }}` but it doesn't work ...

thanks !

Comment: {{ Object.time|date("s.u") }}  ?

Comment: doesn't work for the seconds but almost good for milliseconds (I have 00.600000 but i need xx.600 (just 3 number afer the point))

Comment: "u" will always return pattern 000000  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php  as it is a string you could substring the last part like: {% set foo = Object.time|date("s:u") %}  {{ foo[(foo|length - 3 ), foo|length }}

Comment: This calculation is not natural, so you're going to need to write it yourself and implement it into twig with a [Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @john Smith told in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451625/symfony-twig-datetime-hhmmss-mmm-in-ss-mmm#comment37837659_24451625) (unfortunately I can't +1 but he deserves it), you can use:

```
{{ Object.time | date("s.u") }}
```

To change microseconds to miliseconds, you have 2 choices:

1. [Round](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html) to 3 digits:

   ```
   {{ Object.time | date("s.u") | round(3) }}
   ```
2. [Slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) the 3 last chars:

   ```
   {{ Object.time | date("s.u") | slice(0, -3) }}
   ```